# Android Incoming call and Modify phone state

Tags: android

I have been searching for many days but couldn't find solution for how to accept a call in android well i can Reject call using endcall of ITelephony. but answerRingingCall method is not working.... well another question rises in my mind.

2.I have heard that we cant use modify phone state according to latest android versions.. it it true?? means that they are limited to system apps now what are system apps also Elaborate please.

Thanks

Comment: Google has been removing ways to accept and reject calls programatically in each new release as workarounds are found.  So they definitely don't want you doing it.  I wouldn't expect any way that works to last beyond next release.

Comment: and what about System permission that some stuff like modify_phone_state is allowed for system app?? i can manage to use this in my app but if i upload it to google play will it work ??

Comment: No.  System apps need to be preinstalled.  A rooted phone may be able to make it work, but I'm not absolutely sure if even that's enough.